# Excel for Mac VBA - Go to specific row of table and work up the rows to first row

Tags: macos, vba, excel

I´d like to find a specific row of a table in Excel for Mac 2011. From this row, I want to work up the table to the 1st row. I´m sure there is a simple way of doing it. 
Also, what is the tweak, to work down to the end of the table from a specified row?
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: This can also be a range instead of a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to provide an idea of what you have tried...as well as how you want to find the starting row. Regardless, here I have finding the end row of your data (based on column A, change as needed). This goes to the bottom of the sheet, then essentially does Ctrl + up arrow to get the last row that has something in it. Then starts from there and steps backwards through the rows until row 1. Nb you don't have to set i to endRow, I just did in case you wanted to use endRow for something else.

```
Public Sub testing()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim endRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
endRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

i = endRow

While i >= 1
    'Working up the sheet doing whatever
    i = i - 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works Perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: startRow = 60
endRow = ws.Range("A" & startRow).End(xlUp).row

Will this start at the 60th row and work up?